# Find architecture of processor independent of OS in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, architecture, processor

I am trying to detect whether a device's processor would *support* a 64-bit Windows Operating System installation without paying any attention to the bitness of the Windows Operating System installed on it at the time of the check. I am looking to do this via PowerShell (3.0 minimum), but I can also employ Batch or VBScript by invoking `cmd` and `cscript` respectively. The code must be executable via a non-interactive script, with values being returned without any need for user interaction.

The following methods do not work on my testing device, a 32-bit Windows 10 VM which the *Settings* app identifies as containing an x64-based Processor:

- WMI: Win32_ComputerSystem/SystemType – returns "X86-based PC"
- WMI: Win32_Processor/CPU0/AddressWidth – returns 32
- PowerShell: [intPtr]::size – returns 4 (64-bit devices return 8)
- PowerShell: $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE & IDENTIFIER – return x86
- Registry: HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0 - does not return anything on which a search can be run to ascertain 64-bit instruction capability

I noted above that the *Settings* app can gather this information to tell a user that their device would theoretically support installation of a 64-bit Windows Operating System. Knowing this makes me loth to use a third-party command-line tool (although it remains a viable last resort).

The use case will be to perform this check and then spin off an `if` clause with the information.

Comment: What about Win32_Processor property Architecture - in PowerShell, `(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Processor).Architecture`? The values it should take are one of: 0 - x86; 1 - MIPS; 2 - Alpha; 3 - PowerPC; 6 - ia64; 9 - x64.

Comment: That works, Jeff! Thank you. Please feel free to post it as the answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Done! And thank you!

Comment: `$Env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` also `$Env:PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I already said PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE doesn't work. For the record, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER states that the device is x86-based. Jeff's answer is the only one that is confirmed so far to work.

Comment: Maybe you should confirm you aren't using a 32-bit process then.

Comment: I said "independent of OS".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Win32_Processor` WMI class has a property `Architecture`. This takes the following values, based on the processor type:

- 0 for an x86
- 1 for MIPS
- 2 for Alpha
- 3 for PowerPC
- 6 for ia64
- 9 for x64

So, on a computer with a Core i7 processor, `(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Processor).Architecture` will return `9`, telling you that it's an x64 processor - even if you've installed a 32-bit Windows on it.

Answer (score 1):

Using VB Script you can check AddressWidth for OS type and DataWidth for CPU type. Put the following in a .vbs file:

```
address_width=  GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth
data_width= GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").DataWidth

WScript.Echo "Running " & address_width _
    & " Bit Windows on " & data_width & " Bit processor."
```

There are plenty of ways to determine whether Windows is 32 or 64 bit - but this is the best way I've found to check the Processor type. Took me some time to find it so I thought I'd share in case anyone else is looking  :-)